# Mobx/React and asynchronous animations

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have an event emitter (EE) who emits an event when a ‘next' function is called on it.

I created a store who listen to the events emitted by this EE and stores the event name in an observable.

A bunch of React components do asynchronous stuff (animations) reacting to this observable.

What i want:
Given a current event, i want the store calls ‘next' on the EE only when all the components interested to that specific event completed their animations.

Which is the mob-x way to do that?

Edit: here the code of the store

```
import {observable, autorun} from 'mobx'
    import Solitaire from 'cgk-solitaire'
    import AnimationController from './AnimationController'

    export default class AppStore {
      constructor ({debug = false}) {
        this._debug = debug
        if (this._debug) {
          window.appStore = this
        }
        this._solitaire = new Solitaire({
          game: Solitaire.TRIS
        })

        this._addListeners()

        this.animationController = new AnimationController()

        this.selectedCard = observable.box()
        this.selectedSlot = observable.box()

        this.currentEvent = observable.box()
        this.currentCallback = null
        this.currentStatus = this._solitaire._status // TODO: refactor this

        // Move Reactive Handling
        autorun(() => {
          const card = this.selectedCard.get()
          const slotId = this.selectedSlot.get()
          if (this.currentEvent.get() === 'PLAY' && !!card && Number.isInteger(slotId)) {
            const tableX = slotId < 4 ? 0 : 1
            const tableY = slotId % 4
            const move = this._solitaire.move({card, tableX, tableY})
            this.next(move)
          }
        })
      }

      begin () {
        this._solitaire.begin()
      }

      // Select Card only if the last in hand
      setSelectedCard (card) {
        if (card.id === this.currentStatus.hand.last.id) {
          this.selectedCard.set(card)
        }
      }

      // Select Slot only if a card is selected
      setSelectedSlot (slotId) {
        if (this.selectedCard.get()) {
          this.selectedSlot.set(slotId)
        }
      }

      drawMore () {
        const action = this._action(Solitaire.action.ACT_DRAW_MORE)
        this.next(action)
      }

      setAutoplay (bool) {
        this._solitaire.command(Solitaire.command.CMD_AUTOPLAY, {bool: bool})
      }

      shuffle () {
        this._solitaire._status.shuffleDeck()
      }

      next (payload) {
        if (this.currentCallback) {
          this.currentCallback(payload)
          this._reset()
        }
      }

      _reset () {
        this.selectedCard.set()
        this.selectedSlot.set()
        this.currentCallback = null
      }

      _addListeners () {
        Object.keys(Solitaire.event).forEach(event => {
          this._solitaire.on(event, (status, callback) => {
            this._debug && console.log('*** ' + event + ' ***')
            this.currentStatus = status
            this.currentCallback = callback
            this.currentEvent.set(event)
          })
        })
      }

      _move (data) {
        return this._solitaire.move(data)
      }

      _action (action) {
        return this._solitaire.action(action)
      }

    }
```

Comment: 1. please show us the code you already have. 2. Event Emitter != mobx i think you just needs a plain javascript solution, not a mobx solution. 3. what type of animations are you using? plain css or a library? 4. show your code that you have and why you can't transform it to mobx

Comment: 1) Done, the event emitter is this._solitaire which i listen to at the end with _addListeners
2) It is not so clear to me. The event emitter comes from another package (Solitaire) and i wanted to develop the frontend with mobx.

Comment: 3) Currently i'm using https://greensock.com/gsap
4) Im not synchronizing the various components, i delegated a component (Board) to call next here in the store. If i had to do that i would make each component register in the store to the events they are interested to and they call next on the store when they are done. The store then will check if all the registered components are done before calling the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Event emitters has nothing to do with mobx.

This is what you can do:

1. Make all the listeners that should be awaited return a Promise.
2. Await all promises in the event emitter (bit of anti-pattern but so is wanting to know when listeners are finished)
3. Set mobx state that something is finished (eg with [promise utils](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils))

## return promise on event listener

```
ee.addListener(function(){
  return new Promise((callback,failed)=> {
     this.triggerAnimation(callback);
  })
});
```

## Await promises

event emitter:

```
 function trigger(){
   var results = this.listeners.map(listener=> listener());
   var onlyPromises = results.filter(x=> x instanceof Promise);
   var onAllCompleted = Promise.all(onlyPromises);

   // or:
   onAllCompleted.then(()=> {
      mobxStore.isFinished = true;
   });
   // or: use mobx-utils
   mobxStore.animationState = mobxUtils.fromPromise(onAllCompleted);
 }
```